# How can I add c# code within HTML tags in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating my site from ASP.net Framework (4.7.2) to Asp.net Core (5). One issue that I can't seem to figure out is that in my original site I had c# in a few of my HTML tags to set the css class(es). For instance:

```
<div class="carousel-item propertyCarousel @if (firstImage) { <text>active</text> } @if (slideNumber > 2) { <text>bonus-image</text> } " data-slide-number="@slideNumber.ToString("D2")">
```

Because of tag helpers, asp complains about the code. So I disabled tag helpers in the _ViewImports.cshtml and it no longer complains, but then sometimes the code just doesn't work. For instance in the above example I never get a div with the 'active' class despite verifying the conditions are correct (i.e. that 'firstImage' is true for the first image).

Comment: Needs details or clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the previous commenter did not really answered the question, I'm going to go ahead and say that you need to use brackets for it to work.

This works because it's in a variable:
`<div class="@htmlClass"></div>`

But when you need the result of an expression from within your HTML attribute like:

`<div class="@myvar == true ? "active" : string.Empty"></div>`, does not work. What you should do is wrap it in brackets like this :

`<div class="@(myvar == true ? "active" : string.Empty)"`
This will output: `<div class="active">` if the result of the expression was true.